# Should the output impedance of a function generator be high or low?

Tags: function-generator

As we know, \$R_{load}\$ should be greater than \$R_s\$ on a function generator to avoid loading effect. Does it mean that the output impedance of the function generator should be lower?

Comment: For a typical voltage sourcing function generator an attempt is usually made to minimise the terminal source impedance.  Popular figures are 50 Ohm and 1000 Ohm.  These are used to match similar input impedances in succeeding equipment.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If you want to consider your function generator purely as a voltage source, then yes, the output impedance should be as low as possible. It might be helpful to use a separate buffer amplifier for such applications.

On the other hand, it is often useful to connect a function generator (especially an RF generator) to a transmission line, in which case, you want the output impedance of the generator to match that of the line.

Comment: as I am designing the function generator, the output impedance I measured from my circuit is equal to 50 M ohm, thus it means that my load resistance should greater than 50 Mohm?

Comment: How did you measure the impedance? You can't just stick a multimeter on it, you know.

Comment: From the data sheet, the AD9850 output impedance is 50 - 120 kohm. So it definitely needs an output buffer.

Comment: @DaveTweed, then am I measuring the resistance of the circuit?then how to measure the impedance?by calcualtion?

Comment: To measure a generator's source resistance, you need to make two measurements. The most direct way is to simultaneously measure the output voltage and the output current, but this is often difficult to accomplish in practice. More typically, you would measure the output voltage with two different load resistances, and then solve the simultaneous voltage-divider equations for the source resistance.

Comment: @DaveTweed, then the range for two diffferent load resistances?

Comment: Any two resistances will work, but you'll get the best results (highest resolution) if they're of the same order of magnitude as the source resistance -- which, of course, you don't know yet, so it'll require some iteration.

Comment: @DaveTweed, i have measured three resistance value,R=3k,1k and 100 ohm. The value I　obtained is for R=3K,Idc=1.5756mA, Vdc=4.532V,but the output sine wave Vpp=9V. ANd then for 1K, Idc=4.3511m, Vdc=4.27V and output sine wave also approximate equal to 9V. For 100 ohm, Vdc=2.25V, Idc=22.24mA. By using Rload/(Rload+Rs) * Vs = VL , for R=1k and 3k, I obtained Rs equal to 1192.49ohm, but using R=3k and 100 ohm, applied same equation, I obtained Rs=106.39 ohm, so is it correct? how come have two different sets of Rs?

Comment: If you want to measure the AC source impedance of the generator, you need to make AC voltage and current measurements. You're measuring the DC resistance of the output, which could very well be quite different, and in any case, is irrelevant. In other words, you need to *precisely* measure the peak-to-peak (or RMS) values of the sinewave for each of the three load resistances, and then you can solve for the source impedance.

Comment: @DaveTweed, but the AC voltage if use multimeter to meausre is equal to zero for R=1k and 3k whereas for 100 ohm ,Vac= 23.64mV. Iac for three resistance is equal to zero. From the oscilloscpe, the Vpp for 1k and 3k is 9V and then for 100 ohm is  equal to 3V. Why using multimeter meausre, the voltage and current is zeoro?

Comment: Clearly, you're doing something wrong with the multimeter, or it simply doesn't have the frequency response to handle the generator's output. The 'scope results suggest that the AC source impedance is on the order of 200 ohms.

Comment: @DaveTweed,how to determine a multimeter have a frequency response to the generator output? my frequency of sine wave is about 1 M Hz.

Comment: It will be in the user manual or specification sheet.

Answer (score 3):

An ideal function generator should have zero internal resistance, if its output is in tension. If it is in current it should have infinite internal resistance of course.

What actually happens is that internal resistance can not be zero so usually you can find it in the manual or datasheet or the function generator, and starting from that point you can calculate the maximum, i.e. lowest, load resistance you can connect to your function generator so that the output still suits your needs.

Moreover as you go up in frequency having a low output impedance is not the best choice since you usually want to *match* impedances in order to transfer the maximum amount of power, so instead of having a very low (or very high) output impedance you might want to have an exact finite value for it, not zero nor \$+\infty\$.

For example in the lab at my university we have a function generator for which you can either choose \$50\Omega\$ or a much lower value as output resistance.

Comment: I have a little blur, what does it means of "in current it should have infinite internal resistance"?,that means the output voltage is not important?

why go up in frequency , the low impedance output impedance is not a best choice? actually I have another question about the impedance matching, why low freqeuncy, impedance is negelcted?

Comment: What I meant is that if you need to build a current signal generator, i.e. you want the output to be a current and not a voltage, then its internal resistance must be infinite for it to be ideal. When you go up in frequency strange things happens, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) to start.

Comment: oic, but now I am designing a function generator, the output impedance is 50Mohm, then I want the output be voltage, that means my load impedance should greater than 50M ohm? if lower than 50M ohm, it will distort?

Comment: How can the output impedance be so big? Anyway you won't get distortion but a smaller amplitude: think of it as a voltage divider.

Comment: My design is using this DDS chip module http://www.ebay.com/itm/AD9850-DDS-Signal-Generator-Module-0-40MHz-New-/270864751254, the output impedance is 50Mohm also, and then due to the output amplitude of this module is very low then I design another inverting amplifier with gain=10, and measure againt the output impedance, it is equal to 50Mohm, so I am wondering, am I measure incorrectly? is that possible to have such larger output impedance?

Comment: Well you are measuring it incorrectly. In the datasheet the AD9850 has an output impedance that can reach \$100k\Omega\$. If you add a buffer after that the impedance you want to consider is the buffer output impedance that can be in the range of \$10\Omega\$

Comment: Then anyway to measure the impedance? as I am measure it using multimeter.
I got a question, for the commercial function generator, why we need to set it to high-Z output impedance when we connect it into the oscilloscope to measure the signal?

Comment: For a function generator to have zero effective output resistance, it would in many circumstances have to output infinite current.  In practice, current sourcing/sinking capability is going to be limited.  In many cases, the effects of hitting the current limit during parts of a wave but not other parts would be worse than the effects of adding a constantly-present series resistance to reduce the current demand enough that the generator can always supply it.

Comment: @VladimirCravero, the output amplitude from the AD 9850 data sheet is 1.1VPP?